# What font does the elementary OS logo use

Tags: elementary-website, logo

On the [elementary.io](http://elementary.io) website I see this logo

[image: elementary OS]

The logo is a SVG file (I had to o convert it) and uses a custom R and Y letter. There is also the boot logo which is

[image: boot logo]

Is the first one a custom font or a font. And is the other one another font

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the brand section at elementary OS webpage:

> It is a meticulously-designed brand mark, not simply "elementary" written in a specific font.

More info: [elementary.io Brand](https://elementary.io/en/brand)

Comment: Was this created in inkscape